# Info on my Genie AT-90 remote

Tags: switch, garage-door-opener

I just bought a 1970's house in El Paso, Texas.
I have a Genie Door Opener (screw drive known as the green monster) Model 404.
Along with that I have a Genie Cryptar II Model AR 75 receiver
It works when you press the button at the back door (a doorbell type button)
I have a Genie AT 90 remote that is not working.

The interesting thing is the set up for dip switches on remote and receiver.  They are not sliders but rather tines with a plastic overlay.  I am not sure which is off or on if I get a 9 dip switch replacement.  I have relentlessly scoured google for description.  Are the holes on bottom set to on or off?

[image: Genie Dip Switch with overlay - Remote and receiver same set up]
[image: Genie Dip Switch showing full switches]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: Looks from here like the sheet with holes in it is not in the right position. It appears to be intended to be down between the round contacts and the rectangular ones, not above them. In that position it would allow contact where the holes are and block them where the holes are not. As shown I don't think it does anything.

Comment: All are discontinued items and no explanations from the manufacturer, nor any sites that sell replacement parts (specifically the remote).  The images are from the remote but the actual receiver has the same pattern with only the "7th" hole on top.  If you notice there is a small flap on one end on the right that allows you to lift it.  I tried what you said but 1) it wouldn't fit under the tines and 2) didn't fit flipped upside down.   What you don't see is the lever behind the plastic box that the remote button presses on.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that contact is made where the hole *isn't* over the upturned part of the lever (so only the 7th one)

Comment: To test this, you can hold one of the fingers down on the opener and press the matching one in the remote. If it doesn't work, there's a problem with the battery, the receiver in the opener, or the transmitter in the remote. If it does work, make sure all the contacts are springy and clean, and maybe it'll keep working. I would still go with what I suggested in my answer though if you want to keep using this, because these old remotes are unreliable, insecure, and don't work with Homelink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question was just about the holes. I'm going to answer the broader question I think you might also have, which is: how do I get a working garage door remote?

If you have no luck getting this remote working, there's a fairly inexpensive kit available for retrofit. This consists of a new remote, a box that mounts near the opener, and a power transformer. The kits wire up to power and to the wires that run to the wired button. Once wired in place, they allow you to run the opener via the remote. The Genie kit, for example, is part number GIRUD-1T

I do however suggest that you consider replacing this opener. Though it can be fun to get the old openers working, one of the key features they lack is a safety beam for the door. Older openers only stopped if they sensed a big resistance to the movement of the door. As a result, they regularly crushed kids and pets. Newer openers have an electric eye sensor pair that goes at the bottom of the door, and won't close if there's something blocking the door. It's an important safety feature not present on older openers.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks KMJ.  Because I am curious by nature, the setup intrigued me!  But you are right, a working remote is the best solution.  I did find the exact remote on ebay certified as working as well as a new in box same receiver unit.  Since the main 404 unit is screw-drive, I have to make sure that the limit is set correctly.